# Impossível conectar-se ao servidor remoto - Ao consumir webservice C#

Tags: c#, winforms, web-service

Eu tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em C# que consome um webservice também em C#.

Em alguns casos (não é sempre e não é em todos os lugares/clientes) na hora de consumir o *webservice* eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> **Impossível conectar-se ao servidor remoto**
>     Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu
>     corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou
>     porque o host conectado não respondeu meuip:80

Eu já tive problemas com um outro erro (que estourava na mesma linha) que era:

> Descrição do erro: O nome remoto não pôde ser resolvido: 'webservices.meusite.com.br'

Mas consegui solucionar apenas repetindo a tentativa caso houvesse erro.

O stacktrace mostra o seguinte:

> ```
> em System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>    em System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>    em System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>    em Updater.WebServ.Servico.Metodo(Int32 Id)
>    em Updater.TelaPrincipal.btTeste_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> ```

O mais intrigante de tudo é que não importa quantas vezes eu tente aqui, nunca dá erro. O problema é apenas em alguns lugares.

O que pode estar causando isso?

Comment: Qual é o StatusCode retornado no response? O StatusCode indica se o problema é no cliente ou no servidor.

Comment: acredito que seja problema no Timeout da operação, já verificou a conexão dos seus clientes?

Comment: @TobyMosque A conexão dos que eu testei é praticamente a mesma coisa da minha aqui.

Comment: @RenattoMachado Desculpa a ignorância, mas onde eu vejo o StatusCode?

Comment: @JéfersonTavares aqui tenho uma aplicação que também faz alguns acessos via web, e tenho problemas quando a conexão é 3G tendo que reconectar o modem para que possa funcionar o serviço. Não é esse o caso? A conexão via web de seus clientes é feita de que forma?

Comment: @AndrewAlex ADSL, os dois que eu testei hoje de manhã tinham conexões boas. Mas isso pode ter sido causado por instabilidades ou algo assim então.

Comment: O StatusCode é uma das propriedades do seu response. Você está usando HttpClient para fazer a requisição?

Comment: @JéfersonTavares Isso depende muito dos tipos de operações existentes no seu WebService e da tecnologia aplicada no WebService, voce utiliza WebServices mesmo ou WCF? no seu contrato existe alguma transferência de metadados? a quantidade de dados transmitidos em seus métodos é grande? Ao que parece pode ser um problema de Timeout ou mesmo um limite de cota no tamanho da mensagem.

Comment: @JulioBorges, deve ser timeout então, porque as informações que eu recebo são pequenas strings. Pra constar, eu utilizo webservices, não WCF. E, como eu citei acima, a quantidade de dados transmitida é bem pequena.

Comment: já que após algumas tentativas você obtêm sucesso, o problema está na conexão de internet de seus clientes que não é de boa qualidade. Um software que responde adequadamente em várias máquinas não pode ser o causador da falta de resposta em outras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema deve ser Timeout, tente configurar as chaves de Timeout na chave bindings do arquivo de configuração do software cliente.

```
     <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebServiceSoap"
                 closeTimeout="00:30:00"
                 openTimeout="00:30:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                 allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="655360"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                        maxStringContentLength="8192"
                        maxArrayLength="1638400"
                        maxBytesPerRead="40960"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```